# Session query with multiple inner joins

Tags: php, mysql, session

The following query returns me records of both client id 1 and id 2 .
currently i am logged in with client id 2 .
Did i used the session in wrong place ?

I searched google alot but didn't got success.

```
"SELECT driver_name, we_vehicles.veh_status,
we_vehicles.veh_name, we_vehicles.veh_number_plate,
veh_created_date, we_trackers.tracker_number 
FROM `we_drivers` 
INNER JOIN `we_vehicles` 
ON we_vehicles.veh_id = we_drivers.driver_id 
INNER JOIN `we_trackers` 
ON we_vehicles.veh_id = we_trackers.tracker_id 
WHERE we_vehicles.client_id = ".$_SESSION['client_id'];
```

Comment: Can you share the table structure ??

Comment: structure of all these tables ?

Comment: what is the value of `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: `$_SESSION` value is 2